# как с матрицы смежности построить матрицу инцидентности

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int** matrix(string fileName, int& N, int& M)
{
    ifstream in(fileName);
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        int i, j;
        in >> N >> M;
        int** a = new int* [N];
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            a[i] = new int[M];
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                in >> a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        in.close();
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file text.txt";
        return nullptr;
    }
}
int** matrix2(string fileName, int& N, int& M)
{
    ifstream in(fileName);
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        int i, j;
        in >> N;
        int M = 0;
        int** a = new int* [N];
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            a[i] = new int[N];
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
                in >> a[i][j];
            M += a[i][j];
        }
        M /= 2;
        int I[N][M];
        int C = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
                if (a[i][j]) {
                    I[i][C] = 1;
                    I[j][C++] = 1;
                }
        cout << endl;
        in.close();
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file text.txt";
        return nullptr;
    }
}
void printMatrix(int** a, int N, int M)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << setw(5) << a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 0, M = 0;
    int** a = matrix("text.txt", N, M);
    if (a)
    {
        printMatrix(a, N, M);
    }
    int** b = matrix2("text2.txt", N, M);
    if (b)
    {
        printMatrix(a, N, M);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `M += a[i][j];` должно быть внутри цикла по j

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: Что значит - не работает? matrix2 кого возвращает? Что там везде с размерами напутано?

Answer (score 2):

Имеется матрица смежности `A[N][N]`

Считаете количество единиц в ней (это можно сделать при вводе), делите пополам, получаете `M` - количество рёбер (я подразумеваю неориентированный граф.)

```
int M = 0;
...
  in >> a[i][j];
  M += a[i][j];
...
M /= 2;
```

Создаёте матрицу `I[N][M]`  - т.е. c `M` столбцами, заполненную нулями

Устанавливаете `C = 0` - номер текущего ребра

Обходите половину `A` выше диагонали (c `j>i`), если `A[i][j]==1`, то ставите две единицы в ячейки `I[i][C]` и `I[j][C]` и делаете `C++`

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
   for (int j=i+1; j < n; j++)
       if (a[i][j])  {
          I[i][C] = 1;
          I[j][C++] = 1;
       }
```

Comment: Что из написанного непонятно?

Comment: Я описал все шаги. Судя по приведённом коду, циклы for и операторы присвоения вам знакомы.

Comment: Что именно не поняли?